# django - invalid syntax regex

Tags: django, regex

I'm trying to implement the [solution](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/issues/290) to 
error

```
ImproperlyConfigured
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()
```

Here's my urls.py as suggested

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[\s\d\w().+-_',:&]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(), name = 'account_confirm_email'),
    path('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
re_path(r'^registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[\s\d\w().+-_',:&]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(), name = 'account_confirm_email'),
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea on what I could be missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The syntax highlighting already shows the problem, there is a quite in your regex that *ends* the regex prematurely. You can fix this using double quotes:

from django.urls import include, path, re_path

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(
        r"^registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[\s\d\w().+-_',: & ]+)/$",
        TemplateView.as_view(),
        name='account_confirm_email'
    ),
    path('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

But this will not fix the first error. This is complaining about the fact that you did not pass a `template_name` parameter to the `TemplateView`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(
        r"^registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[\s\d\w().+-_',: & ]+)/$",
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='some_template.html'),
        name='account_confirm_email'
    ),
    path('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

As [@HakenLid says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244194/django-invalid-syntax-regex/62244235#comment110084196_62244235), perhaps you can also simplify the regex to `(?P<key>.+)`, this of course alters the semantics a bit.

Comment: They might also consider using a simpler regex pattern for the "key" group. I suspect `(?P<key>.+)` would probably work fine.